# Unable to access nexus server via IP address in same network

Tags: linux, nexus, nexus3

I have installed nexus repository on Linux machine and I am able to access it via 
http://localhost:8081 and its working fine.

Now I have another machine on same network and I am trying to access nexus using IP address on that machine but it is not working.

http://10.0.2.15:8081/

Can someone help me to fix this ? 
Any configurations that need to be changed ?

Comment: And "it is not working" means _what_ ? Keep in mind that we cannot look over your shoulder, you need to tell us what you see.

Comment: Most likely this is a blocking package firewall, a wrong bind by the nexus setup or maybe a routing issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: sorry for not clearing. "not working" means its giving ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on browser and site can not reach.
I am able to ping from linux to outside. but from other machine can not ping ip address for linux machine

Answer (score 0):

First try to ping somewhere from your linux machine and make sure that you have active connection with outside world. preferably ping your PC.

check whether firewall is active or not.

based on Distro

```
service iptables status
service firewalld status
```

if it is active try stopping and trying again

```
service iptables stop
service firewalld stop
```

Also check selinux,

```
sestatus
```

if it is enforcing, change it to permissive and try again

```
setenforce permissive
```

Please Note that: these arguments are for debugging only. Don't use them on production if you are not sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Add your repository to config  docker daemone.json file in other client.

same:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["10.0.2.15:8081"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I faced when I installed Nexus using a puppet module. I was able to resolve the problem.
I changed the IP and Port at the following location.
**/app/sonatype-work/nexus3/etc/nexus.properties**
You can simply define your bindings by editing this file. After making changes, restart the nexus process. I hope it will help.